# What is the new name of ChromeCustomTabs in android x Library?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, chrome-custom-tabs

I cannot find the new library of **Chrome Custom Tabs** in **Android X**, what is the library name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [migration page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

The new library is `androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0`.